# Problem <mat-chip> on angular material design

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-material

My problem is: i have mat-chip list and if i close the first item it's ok and if i close the last item all are close:

[image]

this is my html:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-chip-list #chipList>
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let keyword of keywords" [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(keyword)">
      {{ keyword }}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input placeholder="{{ 'consultantSearchPage.searchForConsultantOrSkills' | translate }}" [matChipInputFor]="chipList" [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
      (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addSearch($event)">
  </mat-chip-list>
</mat-form-field>
```

and this is my ts:

```js
remove(keyword): void {
  const index = this.keywords.indexOf(keyword);
  if (index >= 0) {
    this._store.dispatch({ type: UPDATE_KEYWORDS, payload: index});
  }
}
```

and if i use:

```js
remove(keyword): void {
  const index = this.keywords.indexOf(keyword);
  if (index >= 0) {
    this.keywords.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

it's ok but my data are not update

and this is my reducer code:

```
export const UPDATE_KEYWORDS = 'UPDATE_KEYWORDS';
.......
case UPDATE_KEYWORDS:
  console.log( state.keywords.splice(0, 1));
  return Object.assign({}, state, { keywords: state.keywords.splice(action.payload, 1) });
```

Comment: Can you show us the code in the reducer or effect that handles the UPDATE_KEYWORDS action?

Comment: export const UPDATE_KEYWORDS = 'UPDATE_KEYWORDS';
.......
case UPDATE_KEYWORDS:
      console.log( state.keywords.splice(0, 1));
      return Object.assign({}, state, { keywords: state.keywords.splice(action.payload, 1) });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment you are doing this:

```
case UPDATE_KEYWORDS:
  console.log( state.keywords.splice(0, 1));
  return Object.assign({}, state, { keywords: state.keywords.splice(action.payload, 1) });
```

whereas you should do this:

```
case UPDATE_KEYWORDS:
  state.keywords.splice(action.payload, 1);
  console.log(state.keywords);
  return Object.assign({}, state, { keywords: state.keywords });
```

You want to use the array that has been spliced, not the array returned from the splice.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Comment: There is a change but it delet just the before item, not the body of item

Comment: @BrunoMarcelino That's strange :-) If `payload` has the correct index value it *should* be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's ok now